# Should I check in my Ctags TAGS file to git?

Tags: git, ctags, etags

Are TAGS files expected to be checked in into git, or are they gitignored?

(They are binary files, so I wasn't sure what the best practice is)

Comment: The TAGS file is not binary. It's plain text. But I wouldn't commit it since it is a product of your source code. Not by itself a source (though it is code of sorts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in general you would not check in the `TAGS` file. The reason is that it's not source code, but it can be easily derived from the source code.

Just like you don't (normally) check in object files or built executables because they can be recreated with a build command, you don't check in the `TAGS` file because it can be recreated using the `ctags` command.